# javascript: how to access the right context

Tags: javascript

I need to write a Javascript code like shown below. Problem is I cannot access "this" (it should point to "obj" on line 1) from within `_notifHandlers.typeA`, `_notifHandlers.typeB` or `_notifHandlers.typeGeneric`.

I understand that I can pass "this" as paramerter to these functions and use it to access the right context.  But is there a better way?

```
var obj = {
    handleNotification : function(managedObj) {

        if (this._notifHandlers.hasOwnProperty(managedObj.id)) {
            this._notifHandlers[managedObj.id](managedObj);
        } else {
            this._notifHandlers.typeGeneric(managedObj);
        }

    },

    _notifHandlers : {
        typeA : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "modelA"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        },
        typeB : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "modelB"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        },
        typeGeneric : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "typeGeneric"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        }
    },

    showUI : function(managedObj, model) {
        // TODO:
        console.log("In showUI(): model -> " + model)
    }
}

var managedObject = {
    id : "typeB"
}

obj.handleNotification(managedObject);
```

Comment: @Andreas In this case, actually no.

Comment: Just use `obj` instead of `this` :-)

Comment: @Bergi - In this example your suggestion should work. But in  my actual code, "obj" is dojotoolkit object.

Comment: @KiranMohan That's why you should post your actual code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `call` method

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/andreitodorut/an15zkja/

```
var obj = {
    handleNotification : function(managedObj) {

        if (this._notifHandlers.hasOwnProperty(managedObj.id)) {
            this._notifHandlers[managedObj.id].call(this,managedObj);
        } else {
            this._notifHandlers.typeGeneric.call(this,managedObj);
        }

    },

    _notifHandlers : {
        typeA : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "modelA"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        },
        typeB : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "modelB"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        },
        typeGeneric : function(managedObj) {
            console.info("_notifHandlers " + managedObj.id + " selected.");
            var model = "typeGeneric"; // TODO:
            this.showUI(managedObj, model);
        }
    },

    showUI : function(managedObj, model) {
        // TODO:
        console.log("In showUI(): model -> " + model)
    }
}

var managedObject = {
    id : "typeB"
}

obj.handleNotification.call(obj,managedObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `bind` to create instances of a function with the context correctly initialized

```
function show(){
    console.log(this.x);
}

x = 10;
var obj = {
    x: 5,
    y:{}
}

// Use bind to create an instance of the function show with the context set to obj and set it to an inner proerty of obj (to mimic the structure of the original posted code)
obj.y.show = show.bind(obj);

show(); //Logs 10 from the global window context
obj.y.show() // Logs 5 with this bound to obj
```

You can also use `call` and `apply` to set the context at the time of invocation.

```
show.call(obj);  // Logs 5
show.apply(obj);  // Logs 5
```

Comment: Also `.call`. `this._notifHandlers[managedObj.id].call(managedObj);`.

Comment: @JimWright yup. `call` and `apply` can be used. I felt bind would be better as it creates a function which is permanently mapped to the instance. Will update answer to show `call` and `apply` as well